# Create an Averager using do-while loop

Tags: java, loops

This program has to prompt the user to input a positive number if they do     not and end ONLY when the user enters -1. The problem I'm running into is how to calculate the actual average after the user enters a negative number and the program keeps going. It calculates the negative number when it shouldn't. How do I get it to print the correct average even after the user enters a negative?

```
package averager;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0; // use for storing addition to all entered values..
        double num, count = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.print("Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: ");
            num = scan.nextDouble();
            sum = sum + num;
            count++;

            if (num <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");

            } else if (num != -1) {
                System.out.println("Average is : " + sum + "/" + count + " = " + (sum / count));
            } else if (num == -1) {
                System.out.println("Average is : " + (sum + 1) + "/" + (count - 1) + " = " + ((sum + 1) / (count - 1)));


            }

        } while (num != -1);

    }

}
```

Comment: surely you should only do `sum = sum + num;` abd `count++` for valid input.  If invalid input, use `continue` to go to the top of your loop.  You could also have `if (num ==-1` break;`

Comment: Is there an actual question here?  Your program _does_ end upon seeing a negative input.  In that case, does it even make sense to print the average again to the user, using the same values which would have been printed in the previous iteration?

Comment: The problem I'm running into is how to calculate the actual average after the user enters a negative number and the program keeps going. It calculates the negative number when it shouldn't.

Comment: It doesn't calculate _any_ number, because the program ends.  Give us a reproducible example please.

Comment: It only ends if the user enters -1. But if they entered say -5, then it calculates it as part of the average. I don't want that -5 calculated or counted as part of the average. The loop has to keep going though.

Comment: See example of the output below:run:

Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: 5
Average is : 5.0/1.0 = 5.0
Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: 6
Average is : 11.0/2.0 = 5.5
Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: -4
Please enter a positive number.
Average is : 11.0/2.0 = 5.5
Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: 5
Average is : 12.0/4.0 = 3.0

Comment: What behavior do you want here?  Do you want to terminate the program with _any_ negative number, or just -1?  If you don't want to terminate with, e.g. -5, then what should happen?

Comment: Just -1, otherwise its required to stay in the loop. The average should calculate as if -5 never happened. It should say "Please enter a positive number" Then the user enters some number and the output is the correct average excluding -5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great place to use `printf` (instead of doing `String` concatenation). Your requirement to use a `do-while` makes it a little more complicated then it might otherwise be, but a logical test is `num != -1`; you can use `continue` to skip negative / zero values. Something like,

```
double sum = 0, num = 0;
int count = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: ");
    num = scan.nextDouble();
    if (num != -1) {
        if (num <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
            continue;
        }
        sum += num;
        count++;
    }
} while (num != -1);
System.out.printf("Average is : %.2f/%d = %.2f%n", sum, count, sum / count);
```

Comment: thanks so much this was helpful. Not sure if I need to include the calculated average after every input or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the logic, you need to assess the input before accepting it and before adding it into calculation.

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0, num, count=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: ");

       do{  
          num = scan.nextDouble(); // get the input
          if(num==-1){// is it -1?          
             if(sum>0){// if yes check if there is any previous input 
               System.out.println("Average is :" + 
                                 sum + "/" + count + " = " + (sum / count));
             }
             else {
                   System.out.println("You chose to terminate the program");
              }
              break; // break the loop 
           }
           else if(num<=0){ // if it's invalid input, inform the user
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number. Try again:");
           }
           else{// the program will reach this point if everything is ok
                // and if the user hasn't terminated the program yet
               sum +=num; // add the number 
               count++; // increment the counter
           }    
        } while(true); // this will break only when user inputs -1
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

**Test1**

```
Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: -1
You chose to terminate the program
```

**Test2**

```
Enter any positive number, enter -1 to quit: -5
Please enter a positive number. Try again:
1
2
3
-1
Average is : 6.0/3.0 = 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use a do while loop!

Comment: your answer's logic flow is terrible

Comment: @Yahya How about showing a certain level of maturity?  If there is a problem then please share it. BTW you do not know what I upvoted or downvoted for

Comment: with what input?

Comment: *Once you underestimate me you prove that you don't know me!*